# On OpenFire, why are buddies' requests for authorization not coming through?

Tags: xmpp, jabber, authorization

On Ubuntu 16.04 (DigitalOcean), I installed OpenFire 4.2.1. So far, I have not yet set up SSL but I have been able to:

1. Connect to the web admin console from home
2. Create some users
3. Use Miranda IM Windows client and Pidgin Windows client to connect to the server and get "online" status
4. Find other users and add them to my contact/buddy list

What I cannot do is receive authorization requests between users.

I ran:

`tcpdump -n -i eth0 'tcp and (port 5222 or port 5269 or port 5280)'`

Then I sent a "re-request for authorization" request from one buddy to another and got this output:

```
23:09:12.295932 IP {IP-of-server}.5222 > {IP-of-requester}.56898: Flags [.], ack 158, win 191, length 0
23:09:12.358987 IP {IP-of-server}.5222 > {IP-of-requester}.56898: Flags [P.], seq 241:481, ack 158, win 191, length 240
23:09:12.492207 IP {IP-of-requester}.56898 > {IP-of-server}.5222: Flags [.], ack 481, win 255, length 0
```

So it seems like the server is receiving the request for authorization, yes? Is there a next step(s) to diagnose the problem? Am I missing something simple?

My server is not heavily hit so I took the risk and briefly disabled its firewall and retried sending the request for authorization, but that didn't seem to make the recipient respond.

Let me know if I am leaving out crucial info that will help you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a bunch of things and now it works so it's one of those cases of not knowing which one(s) fixed it, but for the benefit of others, here is what I did:

1. Add SRV records to my DNS

In OpenFire's admin web console, I did not notice a warning under Server | Server Manager | Server Information: "No DNS SRV records for this host are found". Under that was a lot of useful information about XMPP's need for SRV records, which I had never heard of before. In a nutshell, it is a mechanism for forwarding traffic from one domain to another that XMPP sometimes requires (when the DNS and XMPP server are not hosted on the same server, apparently). A couple things to note: make sure you get the format of the SRV record correct because it is not obvious; using Netfirms as my domain and DNS provider, I had to get their tech support to add the SRV records because within Netfirms, there is no way to manage them.

2. On all the XMPP clients, I changed the account information.

Specifically, for the username info, instead of using xmpp.mydomain.com, I used mydomain.com. For instance, for a username of joe.blow, I entered joe.blow@mydomain.com instead of joe.blow@xmpp.mydomain.com. It wasn't my preference but I kind of suspect this is what made it work.

To this day, I am still confused about the whole XMPP server properties: `XMPP Domain Name` vs. `Server Host Name (FQDN)`. Why does it need both? Why can't it just use the FQDN?

I know this isn't about the question but...

One more OpenFire tip, just in case someone struggled like I did getting secure access to your admin web portal working. If you are using Let's Encrypt for your certificates and you are lucky enough to also be running Apache on the same server then instead of trying to get OF to accept the xmpp.mydomain.com certificate so that you can access your admin portal via https://xmpp.mydomain.com, you can instead use Apache as a reverse proxy. It's much easier stand up, and auto renew, an Apache web server with a Let's Encrypt certificate--at least that's what I found.

Your Apache conf file might look like this (including a redirect for http to https):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName xmpp.mydomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xmpp

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xmpp.mydomain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xmpp.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xmpp.mydomain.com/chain.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9090/

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName xmpp.mydomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xmpp

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https: //%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: NOTE: The site would not accept my RewriteRule [on the grounds was detected as a shortened link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services) so I added a space in the RewriteRule, after `https:`.